# Class C IP Forwarding?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, cloud, ip-address

I'm not even sure how to correctly phrase this question so please bear with me as I try to explain what we want to do. And Thank You for taking the time to help me...

We have products that appeal to an international audience. However with some search engines they factor in what class C/location your domain is sitting on for their serp results.

The problem is we're very familiar with RackSpace cloud servers and their systems. If I had a domain I wanted to appear that it was sitting on a class C in the U.K. but I wanted the actual web server to be in the US (Dallas TX) is there some sort of trick/hack I can use to do so. Something like registering the domain, pointing the DNS to a UK web host and then pulling the files from my US cloud server WITHOUT a search engine (say Google) being able to tell where the site was actually located? I hate to have to jump through hoops like this and feel kinda sneaky doing so but Google certainly factors in IP location into their serps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in the UK that, behind the scenes, pulls data from the US server and returns it to the client.  Google would see this as a UK site, and score it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the perfect solution. Good karma on you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the google webmaster tools to geotarget your web site.  See [here](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=62399&hl=en) for details.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid. I don't give Google any more info than I absolutely have to. They have proven time and time again they'll use it to screw webmasters. Sorry don't mean to get off on a anti-G$ tangent but I don't trust that company with ANY of my data.